# WordPress Move to SSL How to Update Media Assets to HTTPS?

Tags: urls, migration, ssl, https, customization

Migrating a site from HTTP to HTTPS. All images have previously been updated using HTTP so the site is full of mixed content warnings.

What is the best way of sorting this? I've not managed to find any plugins or efficient ways of doing this across the whole site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly common issue when you update your WordPress site's URL from HTTP to HTTPS or if you are migrating to a new domain. While the *WordPress* (`home`) and *Site* (`siteurl`) address have been updated to the new HTTPS link:

[image: Updating your home and site URL]

However, that doesn't mean that your SSL structure in your posts will be fixed. This results in some of your pages pointing to your HTTP link instead, AKA "*getting mixed content warnings*".

[image: SSL mixed content issue (grey lock)]

Try one of the two options:

#### 1. Third-party: [Search/Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

There's a third-party tool tool that allows you

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://web.site/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

#### 2. Plugin: [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)

If you don't have access to your website's source (via FTP, etc.) you can perform the same function by using the [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin within your WordPress site. The process is easy to use and you can also preview what tables and rows will be affected before applying those changes.

**Edit: Michael Cropper**

> For those using the plugin route, I had to use the "Replace Domain URL" option to change from http://web.site to https://web.site, then download the SQL file, then upload this via phpMyAdmin. As always, backup DB before you do this as while this worked for me, may require a few tweaks for yourself.

Comment: Are you aware of a plugin that automates this?

Comment: I do: [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/). It's does the same thing, but in WordPress with a nice UI. Updated my answer.

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks very much. Just going to tweak your answer for more specifics related to that plugin for others using that plugin too.

Comment: Great. Your comment shows up. Glad that helped.

Comment: It's not a good idea to run SQL queries like that on the database; raw queries will will break serialized data in the database, i.e. break widget data, theme options, etc. Use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases . What is the link to the "Search and Replace" plugin? Your links only link an image, not a plugin.

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter what protocol was used to upload the images originally.  You simply need to update the method used to request the assets in your HTML.

If the images (or other assets) are available via an HTTPS request then simply update your code to use HTTPS in the request. If you are using WordPress functions such as `the_post_thumbnail()` to display a featured image, WordPress will automatically use HTTPS for the image once you update the URLs in settings.

Always ensure a good, tested backup exists and perform this work locally or in a dev environment first instead of taking down your production site.

Several good posts on the topic out there for more general info: https://crowdfavorite.com/avoid-ssl-mixed-content-errors-in-wordpress/

Comment: Tried adding the code recommended on that link to the wp-config.php file, no luck unfortunately.