# WordPress Redirect All HTTP requests to HTTPS via .htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I've done this many times before, and yet I'm not managing to do this again for some unknown reason. Tried endless solutions. Everything I've tried results in an endless redirect loop.

What is the best option for doing this?

**Update 1**
Here are a few of the things tried;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

And;

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.co.uk$1 [R,L]
```

Tested in different browsers to prevent caching issues. Still nothing, just getting continual redirect loop.

Comment: Try tracing the redirect:  http://redirectdetective.com/

Comment: Tested that (updated question with additional info) - I've even disabled Google Chrome cache to avoid issues like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: Have you tried the other way arround? `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^433$`

Comment: With the answer [I gave you in your previous question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/236727/98212), did that not fix all of your HTTPS issues? Or are you doing to this to reinforce HTTPS across your website?

Comment: It did for that question yes thanks. I'm wanting to tidy everything up so that if anyone accesses the http version of the site they are 301 redirected to https.

Comment: @MichaelCropper this should be automatically taken care of when you updated the home and site URL so long you have the default `.htaccess` settings that were generated by WordPress.

Comment: It's odd. Seems to automatically 301 redirect on the homepage, but not on the rest of the site. See here, this page is still accessible on HTTP, http://www.michaelcropper.co.uk/contact-me/ - Testing on personal site before rolling out everywhere.

Comment: Be sure to use `@EthanJinksO'Sullivan` so I get notified when you response and I can get back to you quickly. I'll give you my answer below

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I see, when you enter a link to your page other than your home, example:

- `http://www.michaelcropper.co.uk/contact-me`
- `www.michaelcropper.co.uk/contact-me`
- `michaelcropper.co.uk/contact-me`

If `https://` is not in the prefix, the HTTP link loads instead. Add the following into your `.htaccess` in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

If there were no additional modifications done to your `.htaccess`, it should look like the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks @EthanJinksO'Sullivan this worked. Strangely too, I found another setup where I had this working which was very similar to the original setup I tested which also worked this morning `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.michaelcropper.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]` - Based on this I'd have to assume that something somewhere was being cached. Who knows for sure.

Comment: I had to rewrite the code after the RewriteBase \.

Comment: Did not work for me - https rules seems to need to come before, in order to work with inner pages too.

Comment: As the other commenters said: You have to **insert the two lines right after `RewriteBase /`**. In the position shown in the answer, it will only work for the frontpage.

Answer (score 8):

Add code within a .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # BEGIN WordPress
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set header in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This helped me, while none of the above worked.

Comment: +1 This has the benefit that it's less likely to cause conflict with existing `mod_rewrite.c` rules

Answer (score 2):

try this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this in your .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: some explanation why this code would solve OP's question is always nice

Answer (score 0):

If you are using W3 Total Cache the answer from @Ethan Jinks O'Sullivan will only work if you place the redirect before the W3 Total Cache mods in .htaccess as shown below

```
#BEGIN Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
#END Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS

# BEGIN GZIP COMPRESSION
...
# END GZIP COMPRESSION

# BEGIN DEFLATE COMPRESSION
...
# END DEFLATE COMPRESSION

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
...
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
...
# END W3TC Page Cache core

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change anything on .htaccess you may try this out

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_core', 50);
add_action('init', 'redirect_core', 50);
add_action('wp_loaded', 'redirect_core', 50);
function redirect_core(){
  if (!is_ssl()) {
    wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301);
    exit();
  }
}
```

Or try this plugin: [HTTPS Redirect](https://github.com/vindecodex/wp-https-redirect/blob/master/https-redirect.php)

Answer (score -1):

Toke me 10 minutes to fix the issue

Add a conf file for your domain.

Go to centos 7 at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, then create a conf file called `anything.conf`.

Put the following code on it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace `example.com` with your domain.
Then add the https rewrite code on .htaccess its will work. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#BEGIN Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
#END Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: How is your answer different from @ChrisSprague?