# How to make bulk changes to wordpress posts

Tags: import

Part way through developing my WP blog, I changed from HTTP to HTTPS. I followed the instructions I found as best as I could, but ended up with a bunch of old permalinks that are all insistent on being HTTP links. I can easily export all the posts, make manual changes in the backup, but when I go to import, I get the distinct sense it is going to load in my changes on top of what is already there, giving me duplicates of everything, not the import onto a clean slate I'm seeking.

I'm bound to need to do some similar bulk changes in future - what are my options for doing them? Are there ways to make bulk find/replace changes within Wordpress, or if not, how can one export, change, and import in a way that cleans out the old before importing the new?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/236727/11761

Comment: I use and like [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). You could also use [WP-CLI's search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) if you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your site's htaccess file to include this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...changing to your domain name. This takes all port 80 requests (http) and rewrites them to https.

Then, make sure that the `wp_options` table has the `https` URL for your site in both locations.

There are also plugins that will do this for you.